# Determine if a function exists in bash

Tags: bash, function, testing, scripting

Currently I'm doing some unit tests which are executed from bash. Unit tests are initialized, executed and cleaned up in a bash script. This script usualy contains an init(), execute() and cleanup() functions. But they are not mandatory. I'd like to test if they are or are not defined.

I did this previously by greping and seding the source, but it seemed wrong. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Edit: The following sniplet works like a charm:

```
fn_exists()
{
    LC_ALL=C type $1 | grep -q 'shell function'
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I used this to conditionally define stubbed out versions of functions when loading a shell library. `fn_exists foo || foo() { :; }`

Comment: You can save the grep by using `type -t` and `==`.

Comment: Does not work when locale is non-english. `type test_function` says `test_function on funktio.` when using Finnish locale and `ist eine Funktion` when using German.

Comment: For non-english locales `LC_ALL=C` to the resque

Answer (score 269, accepted):

Like this: `[[ $(type -t foo) == function ]] && echo "Foo exists"`

The built-in `type` command will tell you whether something is a function, built-in function, external command, or just not defined.

Additional examples:

```
$ LC_ALL=C type foo
bash: type: foo: not found

$ LC_ALL=C type ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'

$ which type

$ LC_ALL=C type type
type is a shell builtin

$ LC_ALL=C type -t rvm
function

$ if [ -n "$(LC_ALL=C type -t rvm)" ] && [ "$(LC_ALL=C type -t rvm)" = function ]; then echo rvm is a function; else echo rvm is NOT a function; fi
rvm is a function
```

Comment: `type -t $function` is the meal ticket.

Comment: Why didn't you post it as an answer? :-)

Comment: Because I had posted my answer using declare first :-)

Comment: `type [-t]` is nice to *tell* you what a thing is, but when *testing* if something is a function, it's slow since you have to pipe to grep or use backticks, both of which spawn a subprocess.

Comment: Unless I misread, using *type* will have to perform an admittedly minimal access, to check if there is a matching file.  @Lloeki, you're quite correct, but it is the option that produces minimal output, and you can still use the errorlevel. You could get the result without a subprocess, eg `type -t realpath > /dev/shm/tmpfile ; read < /dev/shm/tmpfile` (bad example).  However, **declare** is the best answer since is has 0 disk io.

Comment: @AllanWind You definitely are allowed to write multiple answers, though I suppose back in 2008 this may not have been the case.

Comment: @Lloeki the return value check still works fine, so I could do `type -t foo && echo "foo is something"`, I see no reason to use `declare` instead, as it still produces output that if we need to not show we have to pipe to /dev/null...

Comment: @StevenLu what if you need to know that foo is a function specifically? Isn't that only possible with declare (without using subprocess or Orwellophile's example above)?

Comment: I don't know what I am but I know what I am not, and that's a shell expert.... that being said, it sounds like `declare` is your best friend if you can be satisfied with just a yes/no value as to whether your symbol is a function or not a function, but I was mainly comparing both the syntax and output of `type` and `declare` and it was really obvious that `type -t` is a lot more self-documenting for general purpose shell scripting. You are shell scripting. Subshell to make the script easier to understand? Hell yes.

Comment: The other side of what I was saying was that you can STILL get away without a subshell/pipe/etc if you are satisfied to simply know if your symbol is defined or not (and being a function does satisfy that condition).

Comment: Also see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-type.

Comment: for zsh this becomes `[[ $(type -w foo) == "foo: function" ]] && echo "Foo exists"`

Answer (score 119):

The builtin bash command `declare` has an option `-F` that displays all defined function names.  If given name arguments, it will display which of those functions exist, and if all do it will set status accordingly:

```sh
$ fn_exists() { declare -F "$1" > /dev/null; }

$ unset f
$ fn_exists f && echo yes || echo no
no

$ f() { return; }
$ fn_exist f && echo yes || echo no
yes
```

Comment: worked awesome for me. Especially as my shell doesn't have the -t flag for type (I was having a lot of trouble with type "$command" )

Comment: Indeed, it also works in zsh (useful for rc scripts), and doesn't require to grep for the type.

Comment: @DennisHodapp no need for `type -t`, you can rely on the exit status instead. I have long used `type program_name > /dev/null 2>&1 && program_name arguments || echo "error"` to see whether I would be able to call something. Obviously the `type -t` and the above method also allows to detect the type, not just whether it's "callable".

Comment: @0xC0000022L what if program_name is not a function?

Comment: @DavidWiniecki: not sure what you're referring to?!? I was responding to another comment. If it's not a function it could still be callable and the syntax would be the same, whether alias, function, built-in or external command.

Comment: @0xC0000022L I was nitpicking about how using the exit status doesn't let you know if program_name is a function, but now I think you did address that when you said "Obviously the type -t and the above method also allows to detect the type, not just whether it's "callable"." Sorry.

Comment: To get 1 if function exists and 0 if not exists:
`declare -f $1 > /dev/null && echo 1 || echo 0;`

Comment: What the heck? Any description? Usually, such answers on `StackOverflow` are just humbled with `-1`s.

Comment: I added a description as requested.  Bring on the upvotes :-)

Answer (score 50):

If declare is 10x faster than test, this would seem the obvious answer.

Edit: Below, the `-f` option is superfluous with BASH, feel free to leave it out.  Personally, I have trouble remembering which option does which, so I just use both.  ***-f** shows functions, and **-F** shows function names.*

```
#!/bin/sh

function_exists() {
    declare -f -F $1 > /dev/null
    return $?
}

function_exists function_name && echo Exists || echo No such function
```

The "-F" option to declare causes it to only return the name of the found function, rather than the entire contents.

There shouldn't be any measurable performance penalty for using /dev/null, and if it worries you that much:

```
fname=`declare -f -F $1`
[ -n "$fname" ]    && echo Declare -f says $fname exists || echo Declare -f says $1 does not exist
```

Or combine the two, for your own pointless enjoyment.  They both work.

```
fname=`declare -f -F $1`
errorlevel=$?
(( ! errorlevel )) && echo Errorlevel says $1 exists     || echo Errorlevel says $1 does not exist
[ -n "$fname" ]    && echo Declare -f says $fname exists || echo Declare -f says $1 does not exist
```

Comment: The '-f' option is redundant.

Comment: The `-F` option des not exist in zsh (useful for portability)

Comment: `-F` also is not necessary really: it seems to suppress the function definition/body only.

Comment: @blueyed It may not be necessary, but it is highly desirable, we are trying to confirm a function exists, not list it's entire contents (which is somewhat inefficient).  Would you check if a file is present using `cat "$fn" | wc -c`?  As for zsh, if the *bash* tag didn't clue you in, maybe the question itself should have. "Determine if a function exists in bash".  I would further point out, that while the `-F` option does not exist in zsh, it also does not cause an error, therefore the use of both -f and -F allows the check to succeed in both *zsh* and *bash* which otherwise it wouldn't.

Comment: @Orwellophile `-F` is used in zsh for floating point numbers.  I cannot see why using `-F` makes it better in bash?!  I got the impression that `declare -f` works the same in bash (regarding the return code).

Comment: @blueyed: in **bash** `-F` skips the function definition, and `-f` is superfluous but harmless.  The correct answer was actually `declare -f "$fn"`.  For reasons unknown, I used both flags. It was pure serendipity to later find that in **zsh** the `-F` flag is meaningless but harmless. Given `declare -fF "$fn"` works in both shells, and doesn't require me double checking the arguments, it's an instant winner for me.  And if you can't see why -F is preferable to -f, then you probably consider `cat "$filename" || fail` to be equiv. to `test -f "$filename" || fail`.  Same principle.

Comment: @Orwellophile I got the impression that `-F` would be harmful in zsh, but apparently it is not.

Comment: `return $?` is redundant, remove it and the last exit status will still be returned.

Answer (score 21):

Borrowing from other solutions and comments, I came up with this:

```
fn_exists() {
  # appended double quote is an ugly trick to make sure we do get a string -- if $1 is not a known command, type does not output anything
  [ `type -t $1`"" == 'function' ]
}
```

Used as ...

```
if ! fn_exists $FN; then
    echo "Hey, $FN does not exist ! Duh."
    exit 2
fi
```

It checks if the given argument is a function, and avoids redirections and other grepping.

Comment: Nice, my fav from the group! Don't you want double quotes around the argument too? As in `[ $(type -t "$1")"" == 'function' ]`

Comment: Thanks @quickshiftin; I don't know if I want those double quotes, but you're probably right, although .. can a function even be declared with a name that'd need to be quoted ?

Comment: You're using bash, use `[[...]]` instead of `[...]` and get rid of the quote hack. Also backticks fork, which is slow. Use `declare -f $1 > /dev/null` instead.

Comment: Avoiding errors with empty arguments, reducing quotes, and using the '=' posix compliant equality, it can be safely reduced to::

   `fn_exists() { [ x$(type -t $1) = xfunction ]; }`

Answer (score 12):

Dredging up an old post ... but I recently had use of this and tested both alternatives described with :

```
test_declare () {
    a () { echo 'a' ;}

    declare -f a > /dev/null
}

test_type () {
    a () { echo 'a' ;}
    type a | grep -q 'is a function'
}

echo 'declare'
time for i in $(seq 1 1000); do test_declare; done
echo 'type'
time for i in $(seq 1 100); do test_type; done
```

this generated :

```
declare

real    0m0.064s
user    0m0.040s
sys     0m0.020s
type
    
real    0m2.769s
user    0m1.620s
sys     0m1.130s
```

declare is a helluvalot faster !

Comment: It can be done without grep:


  `test_type_nogrep () {
    a () { echo 'a' ;};
    local b=$(type a);
    c=${b//is a function/};
    [ $? = 0 ] && return 1 || return 0;
  }`

Comment: @qneill I made somewhat more extensive test in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40693218/4414935),

Comment: PIPE is the most slowest element. This test does not compare `type` and `declare`. It compares `type | grep` with `declare`. This is a big difference.

Answer (score 8):

Testing different solutions:

```
#!/bin/bash

test_declare () {
    declare -f f > /dev/null
}

test_declare2 () {
    declare -F f > /dev/null
}

test_type () {
    type -t f | grep -q 'function'
}

test_type2 () {
     [[ $(type -t f) = function ]]
}

funcs=(test_declare test_declare2 test_type test_type2)

test () {
    for i in $(seq 1 1000); do $1; done
}

f () {
echo 'This is a test function.'
echo 'This has more than one command.'
return 0
}
post='(f is function)'

for j in 1 2 3; do

    for func in ${funcs[@]}; do
        echo $func $post
        time test $func
        echo exit code $?; echo
    done

    case $j in
    1)  unset -f f
        post='(f unset)'
        ;;
    2)  f='string'
        post='(f is string)'
        ;;
    esac
done
```

outputs e.g.:

> test_declare (f is function)
>
> real  0m0,055s user   0m0,041s sys    0m0,004s exit code 0
>
> test_declare2 (f is function)
>
> real  0m0,042s user   0m0,022s sys    0m0,017s exit code 0
>
> test_type (f is function)
>
> real  0m2,200s user   0m1,619s sys    0m1,008s exit code 0
>
> test_type2 (f is function)
>
> real  0m0,746s user   0m0,534s sys    0m0,237s exit code 0
>
> test_declare (f unset)
>
> real  0m0,040s user   0m0,029s sys    0m0,010s exit code 1
>
> test_declare2 (f unset)
>
> real  0m0,038s user   0m0,038s sys    0m0,000s exit code 1
>
> test_type (f unset)
>
> real  0m2,438s user   0m1,678s sys    0m1,045s exit code 1
>
> test_type2 (f unset)
>
> real  0m0,805s user   0m0,541s sys    0m0,274s exit code 1
>
> test_declare (f is string)
>
> real  0m0,043s user   0m0,034s sys    0m0,007s exit code 1
>
> test_declare2 (f is string)
>
> real  0m0,039s user   0m0,035s sys    0m0,003s exit code 1
>
> test_type (f is string)
>
> real  0m2,394s user   0m1,679s sys    0m1,035s exit code 1
>
> test_type2 (f is string)
>
> real  0m0,851s user   0m0,554s sys    0m0,294s exit code 1

So `declare -F f` seems to be the best solution.

Comment: Attention here: `declare -F f` doesn't return non-zero value if f doesn't exists on zsh, but bash yes. Be careful using it. `declare -f f`, by another hand, works as expected attaching the definition of the function on the stdout (which can be annoying...)

Comment: Have you tried `test_type3 () { [[ $(type -t f) = function ]] ; }` there is a marginal cost of defining a local var (although < 10%)

Answer (score 7):

It boils down to using 'declare' to either check the output or exit code.

Output style:

```
isFunction() { [[ "$(declare -Ff "$1")" ]]; }
```

Usage:

```
isFunction some_name && echo yes || echo no
```

However, if memory serves, redirecting to null is faster than output substitution (speaking of, the awful and out-dated `cmd` method should be banished and $(cmd) used instead.) And since declare returns true/false if found/not found, and functions return the exit code of the last command in the function so an explicit return is usually not necessary, and since checking the error code is faster than checking a string value (even a null string):

Exit status style:

```
isFunction() { declare -Ff "$1" >/dev/null; }
```

That's probably about as succinct and benign as you can get.

Comment: For maximum succinctness use `isFunction() { declare -F "$1"; } >&-`

Comment: `isFunction() { declare -F -- "$@" >/dev/null; }` is my recommendation.  It works on a list of names as well (succeeds only if all are functions), gives no problems with names starting with `-` and, at my side (`bash` 4.2.25), `declare` always fails when output is closed with `>&-`, because it cannot write the name to stdout in that case

Comment: And please be aware, that `echo` can sometimes fail with "interrupted system call" on some platforms.  In that case "check && echo yes || echo no" still can output `no` if `check` is true.

Answer (score 4):

From my comment on another answer (which I keep missing when I come back to this page)

```
$ fn_exists() { test x$(type -t $1) = xfunction; }
$ fn_exists func1 && echo yes || echo no
no
$ func1() { echo hi from func1; }
$ func1
hi from func1
$ fn_exists func1 && echo yes || echo no
yes
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Invocation of a function if defined.

**Known function name**. Let's say the name is `my_function`, then use

```
[[ "$(type -t my_function)" == 'function' ]] && my_function;
# or
[[ "$(declare -fF my_function)" ]] && my_function;
```

**Function's name is stored in a variable**. If we declare `func=my_function`, then we can use

```
[[ "$(type -t $func)" == 'function' ]] && $func;
# or
[[ "$(declare -fF $func)" ]] && $func;
```

**The same results with `||` instead of `&&`**
(Such a logic inversion could be useful during coding)

```
[[ "$(type -t my_function)" != 'function' ]] || my_function;
[[ ! "$(declare -fF my_function)" ]] || my_function;

func=my_function
[[ "$(type -t $func)" != 'function' ]] || $func;
[[ ! "$(declare -fF $func)" ]] || $func;
```

**Strict mode and precondition checks**
We have `set -e` as a strict mode.
We use `|| return` in our function in a precondition.
This forces our shell process to be terminated.

```
# Set a strict mode for script execution. The essence here is "-e"
set -euf +x -o pipefail

function run_if_exists(){
    my_function=$1

    [[ "$(type -t $my_function)" == 'function' ]] || return;

    $my_function
}

run_if_exists  non_existing_function
echo "you will never reach this code"
```

The above is an equivalent of

```
set -e
function run_if_exists(){
    return 1;
}
run_if_exists
```

which kills your process.
Use `|| { true; return; }` instead of `|| return;` in preconditions to fix this.

```
    [[ "$(type -t my_function)" == 'function' ]] || { true; return; }
```

Answer (score 3):

This tells you if it exists, but not that it's a function

```
fn_exists()
{
  type $1 >/dev/null 2>&1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I particularly liked solution from [Grégory Joseph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9002012/216172)

But I've modified it a little bit to overcome "double quote ugly trick":

```
function is_executable()
{
    typeset TYPE_RESULT="`type -t $1`"

    if [ "$TYPE_RESULT" == 'function' ]; then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}
```

Comment: his original solution hould work if he puts `type` call inside the quotes.

Answer (score 3):

```
fn_exists()
{
   [[ $(type -t $1) == function ]] && return 0
}
```

*update*

```
isFunc () 
{ 
    [[ $(type -t $1) == function ]]
}

$ isFunc isFunc
$ echo $?
0
$ isFunc dfgjhgljhk
$ echo $?
1
$ isFunc psgrep && echo yay
yay
$
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check them in 4 ways

```
fn_exists() { type -t $1 >/dev/null && echo 'exists'; }
fn_exists() { declare -F $1 >/dev/null && echo 'exists'; }
fn_exists() { typeset -F $1 >/dev/null && echo 'exists'; }
fn_exists() { compgen -A function $1 >/dev/null && echo 'exists'; }
```

Comment: What are the differences between all these?

Answer (score 2):

I would improve it to:

```
fn_exists()
{
    type $1 2>/dev/null | grep -q 'is a function'
}
```

And use it like this:

```
fn_exists test_function
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo 'Function exists!'
else
    echo 'Function does not exist...'
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use 'type' without any external commands, but you have to call it twice, so it still ends up about twice as slow as the 'declare' version:

```
test_function () {
        ! type -f $1 >/dev/null 2>&1 && type -t $1 >/dev/null 2>&1
}
```

Plus this doesn't work in POSIX sh, so it's totally worthless except as trivia!

Comment: test_type_nogrep () { a () { echo 'a' ;}; local b=$(type a); c=${b//is a function/}; [ $? = 0 ] && return 1 || return 0; } – qneill