# Check if a function exists before executing it in shell

Tags: linux, function, shell, ash

I want to check if a function exist or not before executing it in the shell script.

Does script shell support that? and how to do it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85880/determine-if-a-function-exists-in-bash - but you mention ash, not sure if that solution works in ash as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As read in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85880/determine-if-a-function-exists-in-bash#comment11457_85903), this should make it:

```
type -t function_name
```

this returns `function` if it is a function.

#### Test

```
$ type -t f_test
$ 
$ f_test () { echo "hello"; }
$ type -t f_test
function
```

Note that `type` provides good informations:

```
$ type -t ls
alias
$ type -t echo
builtin
```

Comment: Is `-t` available in `ash`? It's not POSIX, so I wonder if it is a `bash` extension.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know it, @chepner.

Answer (score 1):

POSIX does not specify any arguments for the `type` built-in and leaves its output unspecified. Your best bet, apart from a shell-specific solution, is probably

```
if type foo | grep -i function > /dev/null; then
   # foo is a function
fi
```

Comment: Do not use this. Depending on the language of the user the word "function" may not exists in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can always just try executing the function. If it doesn't exist, the exit status of the command will be 127:

```
$ myfunction arg1 arg2 || {
>  if [ $? -ne 127 ]; then
>    echo Error with my function
>  else
>    echo myfunction undefined
>  fi; }
```

Of course, the function may have the same name as another binary, and you may not want to run that program if it is not shadowed by the function.

Comment: What if the function is destructive (think `make clean`)? What if the function itself returns 127 or its last command does? I wouldn't want to run a reboot function just to see if it exists...

Comment: The first point is valid. I would argue that if the function itself returns 127, that's a bug in the function, as it is defined by POSIX to mean "command not found". I was working on the assumption that if he's going to call it if it exists, there's no harm in just trying to call it first.