Bash wants unary operator
I am using the following code to test if a function exists but Bash gives the following diagnostic:
[: =: unary operator expected
The code is:
if [ $(type -t deactivate) != function ];

How should this be expressed in a shell script independent manner?

What is a "shell script independent manner"?

Learn to use https://shellcheck.net . Copy/paste your code there and fix any errors flaged. Be sure to include #!/bin/bash (or other) as your first line of scripting. As you want independence, you can probably find code that will work with #!/bin/ksh ; #!/bin/ksh93 ; #!/bin/zsh ; #!/bin/sh ; #!/bin/dash Good luck.

I want this statement to be usable in any shell program such as Bash, CSH, ZSH etc.

@Jonathan csh has very different syntax from the Bourne-family shells (sh, ksh, bash, zsh, dash, etc). If you value your sanity, don't try to make things portable between it and anything else (except tcsh).

@Gordon Davisson Are you suggesting that a completely different script becomes necessary? I know this is the case for Microsoft PS1.

@shelter The problem comes when I cannot find out how to fix reported problems.

The quick fix for the Bash specific error you see is to put double quotes around $(...).

Benjamin W That did the trick, thankyou.

@Jonathan Why would you want the script to be runnable under csh as well as bash etc? It's generally best to pick a specific shell and write for that (using an appropriate shebang for it). Writing broadly portable scripts tends to be difficult. If you need it to be able to run in a variety of unixish environments, the best method is to restrict yourself to the basic functions and syntax required by POSIX, which should work in most Bourne-family shells. But you have to know what those limits are; for example, type -t won't work in anything but bash (and tcsh and maybe csh).

Why do you care about other shells, after all the script will be executed by the one in the shebang (.i.e. #! /usr/bin/env bash) for OSs that honors that.

Gordon Davisson Because the underlying system should be able to run in any environment. This script is actually a front end to the Python virtual environment activation support which is expected to run almost anywhere.

Diego Torres Milano The script is sourced and the system that it invokes will not run properly unless this happens. The script actually checks to see if it is sourced before running. The script should run properly when invoked from any shell.

Gordon Davisson You identified the problem that I am facing. I have been unable to find a good source that defines what will work in different shells so I am faced with trial and error.

@Jonathan That's because what you're trying to do is not a reasonable thing. It's a bit like trying to write a manual that can be read in English, French, German, Russian, etc. It's something someone might take on as a challenge -- basically, a programming dare -- not something you'd actually do as part of a serious project.

Use [[ and ]]. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/85903/3776858

Cyrus They are not portable to all scripting languages.

@Gordon Davisson You have identified one of the major problems with the current software environment - fragmentation due to many different incompatible wys of doing things. I believe that it is possible to do something about this but it will need a lot of new tools. In order to have a chance of doing this I have to start with the current environment and do things step by step. The software that has the problem here is part of a first stage that uses the current environment.

@Gordon Davisson  I admit that I may be pushing the envelope a bit but I have only got one problem remaining in the current software, namely how to rcognize whether a function is available in a shell script. I have this working in the Bash environment but you are correct that my current way of doing it is not portable. If I have to, I can build script language speific code into my stuff but I would rather not.

FWIW, ksh93 (possibly earlier versions too) respond to type fn_name with fn_name is a function

How do you invoke this script? Do you want to run it on almost any system or in almost any shell?

The script must be sourced which means that it must be syntactically compatible with the parent shell environment that invokes it.

When you want the script sourced, perhaps use a wrapper that sources the right native script. Perhaps with aid of a variable set in your shell dependent login script. This will introduce maintaining different scripts, but this is better than a multi-language script that nobody can maintain.

@Walter A I had considered this but I was hoping for a shell independent solution and I am having trouble finding the shell specific way of determining whether a functon exists in zsh. The type specification is bash specific.

The basic syntax of if is incompatible between (t)csh and all the other shells. So any attempt to make a non-trivial script that's portable between them is doomed.

It is in general not possible to use the same syntax for csh and bash.
As for the error in your script: it is probably caused by the fact the type -t deactivate does not produce output. Proper quoting will solve that issue:
if [ "$(type -t deactivate)" != "function" ] ; then


I did not realize that csh and bash used different syntaxes when I asked this question. This implies that I will need multiple versions of the script for different shell environments.  however your suggestion on quoting answers my specific question.  Since I want to make this script at least usable in all Bourne based shells I am abandoning the use of the type command as not being portable and have found a shell agnostic solution using the typeset -f command. Your suggestion on quoting helped me here as well as I am definitely not a shell expert.
